# Jupyter notebook timeouts

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, jupyter

TL;DR: Calling requests within a notebook causes it to hang forever if the endpoint takes more than some threshold of time.  Calling the same endpoint in a cell using !curl always returns a response.

To give a bit more detail:

I have an issue with a potential timeout in jupyter notebooks.  I first observed the issue in a managed notebook in the cloud, but have since succeeded in replicating it locally.

I'm calling an endpoint from within the notebook which can take up to 6mins to execute.  If the endpoint takes ~5.5m or less I get a response, but if it takes longer than this it will hang (seemingly) forever.

I first suspected this was one of the timeouts in the nnotebook config, so I increased all of them, but still observed the problem. Next I tried calling curl from within the notebook, and this works, even if if the endpoint takes far longer than 5.5m.  This implied that it might be my use of the requests python package.  Even though no timeout was specified, I set this to something large (600s).  In this case requests closes the connection after 600s (even though I know the server should return a response after ~330s).  If I explicitly disable the timeout by setting it to None, again it seems to hang forever (no response after at least an hour).

Does anybody have any suggestions what the issue could be, or perhaps suggest how I might further diagnose it.

Thanks!

Best wishes,

A.

Comment: please include examples of your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the solution using wireshark.  It turns out curl is sending TCP Keep Alive packets every 60s, which resets the 330s idle timeout, however, the requests library get method is not sending this packet.  I changed the default socket options of HTTPConnection (in urllib3 which underpins requests) to emulate those of curl (i.e., keep alive with a 60s interval), and have had no further issues.